# Having this minor error using Dart

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
double base = 1, bnry = 0, remainder = 0, ans = 0, inp;
print("Please input binary number : ");
inp = stdin.readLineSync();
bnry = inp;
while(inp < 1){
    remainder = inp % 10;
    ans = ans + remainder * base;
    base = base * 2;
    inp = inp / 10;
}
print("$inp");
}
```

this is my code and here is the error message

> unhandled exception:
>   Class 'String' has no instance method '<'.
>   NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '<'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a string from `stdin.readLineSync()`. You need to convert it to number  in order to be able to compare it to another number

```
inp = num.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```